Objects Disappearing When in Top-Down View (And Array/Curve Modifier Oddities) (Blender 4.2.3)
I'm trying to edit a map from a game by building roads using curves. The best "workflow" I know of is to go into top-down view to move each node of the curve on the X and Y axis before going into normal view to change the height on the Z axis. The issue here is that when I go into top-down view, the road disappears. How do I fix this? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the clip start and end variables in the view properties.


Also, not related to this issue, but something I'd love to solve:
These roads are made by building a mesh that is 12 meters long and using an Array modifier with a Curve modifier, both set to target the same curve object. This works amazingly to have the road follow the curves while maintaining nearly-perfect spacing between the yellow lines. The issue, however, is that the road extends a very long way past the end of the curve. How do I cut it off at the end of the curve? The longer the curve, the longer the road extends beyond the end.



Even if it seems as if the road disappears - at least where it is supposed to be, there is a different color than the background. Could it be there is an object higher than the road which is obstructing the view? Because in Top Orthographic view you are basically infinitely high, so whatever is in place there no matter how high will be between the viewer and the road. Unless it is below the road. You could switch to bottom up view (Ctrl+Numpad 7 or when in top down view, press Numpad 9 to switch to the opposite) and see if the road is visible then.

if Gordon's answer doesn't work, please share your file

There is nothing above it. Here is the file in question. It is a big file as it includes the entire game map I am editing (which is roughly 30km x 15km in size). This road is on the north edge near the eastern airport (X: 25641.8 m, Y: 13525.6 m, Z: 8.63209 m)
https://mega.nz/file/Rw9hnKTT#SPSgQUfCQMzKvBIMjA5Jbql_DGZnVPS5a7lM75vfRA4

The road extends so far because you have scaled the road piece in Object Mode and did not apply the scale, i.e. the Scale X, Y, Z values are different from 1 (the X value being the one responsible for the "extension"). Apply the scale with Ctrl+A > Apply > Scale. This is by the way one of the most common reasons when objects show weird behaviour so you should always check that. If applying the scale does not solve it, we probably need more information or your file.
For the main question: maybe it would help if you upload your file. Apart from that, this is a Q&A site where it is preferred to have one topic per posted question, and the disappearing road and the extended are two completely different issues, so it would be best to make a second post. So I would actually prefer posting this answer on a new question, but since the main question lacks information what your scene contains which could result in making the road disappear, I answered the second question.

This solved that problem! Thank you! Sorry for pairing the two, I didn't think having two separate posts at about the same time would be nice.

@BobGrey If it's two different topics it is always better to have two separate posts. Some people look through the titles if they sound like they could help... either titles can become very long and confusing or some topics inside the post are left out in the title so they get overlooked by people who might have been able to help. It's no problem to post several questions at the same time as long as they have different. It would be same if you post about one topic and someone else posts about a different topic at the same time - we will not forbid him to post at the same time as you.

@Bob Grey if it solved the problem, mark the answer as correct   ;)
